# CrystalReportViewer_Error: There is an error in XML document (179, 23)

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I loaded a file from S3 bucket using reportDocument.Load() and Crystal report viewer loaded the rpt file. I have few links in the rpt fie. When clicking those links, Im getting

CrystalReportViewer_Error: There is an error in XML document (179, 23)